# Setting an entity's ID manually

Tags: jspresso

I'm facing a little issue that I cannot understand here.
Using this chunk of code:

```java
IEntity myEntity = controller.entityFactory.createEntityInstance(MyEntity.class)
myEntity.straightSetProperty(IEntity.ID, "anId")
myEntity.setReferenceProperty(someReference)
```

I get an "UOW bad usage" error

> *BAD SESSION USAGE* You are modifying an entity ()[MyEntity] that has not been previously merged in the session.
>       You should 1st merge your entities in the session by using the backendController.merge(...) method.
>   The property being modified is [referenceProperty].

But when switching the lines it's okay

```java
IEntity myEntity = controller.entityFactory.createEntityInstance(MyEntity.class)
myEntity.setReferenceProperty(someReference)
myEntity.straightSetProperty(IEntity.ID, "anId")
```

Any idea why i'm facing this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jspresso computes the **hashcode** of an entity based on its **id**. this hashcode is indirectly used by Jspresso internally to perform some controls and other operations by using it in `Hash[Map|Set]`.

That's why it's mandatory that :

1. The id is assigned as soon as the entity instance is created *and* before any setter or operation is performed on the entity.
2. The id does not change during the lifetime of the entity.

When you call :

```java
IEntity myEntity = entityFactory.createEntityInstance(MyEntity.class)
```

a generated id is assigned to the entity.

In scenario 1, you first change the id (which breaks the hashcode), and call a setter. Jspresso thinks this entity has not been correctly registered because it cannot retrieve its id from the internal, hashcode based, storage.

In scenario 2, same violation but you call the setter *before* changing the id. But I suppose that if you call another setter afterwards, it will fail the same way.

The solution is to use the other signature of the `entityFactory` create method that allows to pass an id as parameter, e.g.

```java
IEntity myEntity = entityFactory.createEntityInstance(MyEntity.class, "anId")
myEntity.setReferenceProperty(someReference)
```

which will immediately assign your id to the entity and perform all necessary operations afterwards.